# Hiding planes yet keep emissive or bounce lighting in the viewport

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Is there a way to hide a plane so I can view from different angles without it blocking the camera in eevee viewport?

Im using SSGI to get nice bounce light but its blocking the view from some angles

Also would like to know if the same can be applied to an emmissive plane, where I can hide it yet still have its light affects in eevee viewport with ssgi on

Comment: SS stands for Screen-Space, which means calculations are only done in your current view, that being the viewport or through a camera. I don't think there's a way to have emissive planes outside the view and have it interact with other objects.

Comment: so the only way is to render it in cycles and do that hide camera and shadow trick?

Comment: I don't know how your scene set up or what you want to accomplish, but yes, to have mesh emitters outside the view that lights up your scene, you need cycles.

Comment: Have you tried the (Input) Geometry node > Backfacing output? You can make one of its side transparent, maybe it will fit your needs?

Comment: Oh do you think you could have a step by step on how to do this? Im still quite new and would very much appreciate a visual aid